# how do add an additional filter function in google appscript to reference a column and searching for text "TMO"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is the code I have for searching by a specific color. I would like to then like to also filter by the word TMO in column K

```
function TmoSuspended () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Boost Prod Account Info")
  /*var cell_color = ss.getRange("A4").getBackground(); #fff2cc
  Logger.log(cell_color);*/
  var last_row = ss.getLastRow();
  var array = ss.getRange(1, 1, last_row).getBackgrounds();
  var allRows = ss.getRange("A:A");
  
ss.unhideRow(allRows);

for (i=8 ;i <= last_row;i++){

if(array[i] != "#f1c232")
{

ss.hideRows(i+1)};
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, please clarify, By you mean TMO, is it full or partial in word?

Comment: Hi there, TMO would be the full text

Comment: Can you please clarify, what is your expected output? do you expect to keep rows with `"TMO" and #f1c232` OR you just need either #f1c232 or "TMO"?

Comment: so i would need to return rows that are not equal to #f1c232 and "TMO"

Answer (score -1):

As what I have understood from your concern, you may try this code:

This will hide rows with color #f1c232 in column A and "TMO" word in column K.

**Try:**

```
function TmoSuspended() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Boost Prod Account Info")
  var array = ss.getRange("A:A").getBackgrounds();

  //Checker of color (""#f1c232"") on column A  and return true if not equal to blanks and word 'TMO'
  try { var res = array.map((color, index) => { return color[0] == "#f1c232" ? [true, ss.getRange('K:K').getValues().map(x => { return x != '' && x.toString().match(/TMO/gm) })[index]].flat() : false }) } catch { }

//This will return rows that are not equal to #f1c232 and "TMO"
  console.log(res.map((x,index) => {return x[0] == true && x[1] == "TMO" ? ss.hideRows(index+1) : null}))

}
```

Let me know if this helps.